# How to match one or more characters in a string with regex?

Tags: regex

Let's say I have a string, for example `"abcdef"`.

I want to match one or more characters in order from the start of the string, for example:

```
"a"
"abc"
"abcd"
```

So, it might look a little like this:

```
/^(abcdef{1,})/
```

But obviously here the quantifier only applies to the preceding character (`"f"`) whereas I want it to apply to the entire string (`"abcdef"`). I am hoping there is something I can enclose `"abcdef"` in to achieve this.

I am using `preg_match()`.

Comment: Do you mean to match as many as possible in the order `abcdef`?

Comment: You need character class: `/^[abcdef]+$/`

Comment: after match what you want to do?

Comment: Washington Guedes - yes, I have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Vigneswaran S - I am using preg_match and would like to set a variable to the matching part of the string using that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the order is important, you can use this regex:

```
\ba(b(c(d(ef?)?)?)?)?
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/nW5rG5/2)

Comment: Good regex, I think `\b` and the most inner parentheses are not needed: `^a(b(c(d(ef?)?)?)?)?`

Comment: @Termininja. You are right, the most inner parentheses isn't needed. I've also updated the link with one more test to see the need of `\b`, but as you pointed can be `^` instead.

Comment: The point here is to note that `f` is only optional if `e` is there. Same as `e` is for `d`, or `d` is for `c`, and so on... And to avoid grouping, just need to change `(...)` for `(?:...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Another variant to match exactly *"one or more characters from the start of the string"* is:

```
^(abcdef|abcde|abcd|abc|ab|a)
```

Comment: I like this answer for easy readability and also because it puts the match into a single set of parentheses. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need is to enclose `abcdef` as a set. Try something like

```
/[abcdef]{1,}/
```

Comment: Order is important, sorry for not clarifying. I have edited the question.